# How to Return the SQL_DB log files (.ldf) to the default Application

Tags: windows, sql-server, log-files, sql-server-2014, defaults

I have tried to open a "**log**" file of SQL DB with Windows Notepad application. Unfortunately, I forgot to remove the tick from the checkbox of “Always use the selected program to open this kind of file”. Therefore, all log files of my SQL DBs have been changed to Notepad icon.

Please help me to find a way to return this type of file to the default application.

**Note**: I'm using SQL Server 2014 on Windows 7 operating system.

Comment: there are lot of multiple reasons of offtopic in here, but the same way change the default back to a other application.  it's well known as standard applications. it's well documented on the internet

Comment: Tell the windows version - that said, this is so basic any AI an answer that. But the exact steps to undo a file opening tool are windows version dependent.

Comment: **HOW TO REMOVE A FILE ASSOCIATION WINDOWS 7** https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

You can not return it to the default application because there is no default application - .log files are not supposed to be opened with anything except SQL Server. The steps to undo an assignment are - windows version specific, the UIÄs changed over time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default application to open those files, they are binary files used by the SQL Server storage engine and are not meant to be accessed directly.

The ".log" file extension makes quite easy to confuse them for real log files, so this is actually a common mistake. Anyway, the icon you see is completely irrelevant to their working, so there's nothing in need of fixing here.

If you really want to remove the file association, this question should help you: https://superuser.com/questions/49615/how-do-you-remove-a-default-program-association-for-file-types-in-windows-7

Comment: That a not the question actuall.y